# Print JavaRDD on IDE console with Spark cluster deployed on remote machine

Tags: java, apache-spark, remote-access, rdd

I Have a spark  (1.6.2) standalone cluster deployed on a remote machine (1 master and 1 worker). I am connecting to this cluster using Java from IntelliJIdea on local machine. Find below java code for the same -

```
            SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("localApp").
            setMaster("spark://remoteHostMaster_1:7077").
            set("spark.ui.port","7077");
            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

Spark monitoring UI is launching fine at http://remoteHostMaster_1:8080/ and is displaying details of worker node.

I write a simple map-reduce and print JavaRDD on console.

If I use setMaster("local[x]") in SparkConf Object, everything works fine (console printing and file writing of JavaRDD).

Issue is whenever I print JavaRDD or write JavaRDD to a file, I am getting below exception -

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, remoteHostWorker_1): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.til.socialData.SocialGraphDataSpark$1
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please guide regarding this. If anybody finds any duplicate or related question, please mention in comments.

Thanks and Regards,

Vibhav